# Failed commissioning machine on MAAS

Tags: maas

I try to add a machine in MAAS. There is an error, MAAS failed to know power state on it machine, the connection is time out.

I test ping from MAAS to the server is OK. But when run the command "ipmipower", appear the connection is time out.

[IPMI Command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfLBS.png)

[machine events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATC5R.png)

Below are my environment :

Server           : Dell PowerEdge R730xd 
IPMI Version     : 2.0 
Firmware Version : 2.40.40.40 
MAAS Version     : 1.9.4+bzr4592-0ubuntu1 (trusty1)

I hope anyone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Enable IPMI Over LAN on iDRAC Setting - Network.

It's worked for me and able to manage power from "ipmipower" command.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)